# how to make a ul same size as parent li?

Tags: html, css

I'm working a dropdown menu, but I'm having a problem with the size of inner `ul` I trying to make it the same size as the parent `li`.

Can somebody tell me what am i doing wrong?

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/o9kkb1er/1/) is a demo of my code.

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
ul.topMenu {
  background: #111;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul.topMenu li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
ul.topMenu li a {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .4s;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}
ul.topMenu li:first-child a {
  border-left: 1px solid #222222;
}
ul.topMenu li a:hover,
ul.topMenu li a:focus {
  background: black;
}
ul.topMenu ul {
  position: absolute;
  background: #222;
}
ul.topMenu ul li {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="topMenu" class="topMenu">
  <li><a href="#">Sed ut perspiciatis </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Nemo enim </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sit amet </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Excepteur </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Neque  </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Neque porro </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Ut enim ad </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Quis autem vel eum </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sit amet </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Excepteur </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Neque  </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So you want each submenu to be the same width as the parent item or you just want to get rid of the default submenu list padding?

Comment: @j08691 i want the submenu the same with as the parent "li"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Notes:**

- In order to make your **`ul`** element as wide as its **`li`** parent, you have to change its position to **`position: relative`**, so that you can use **`width: 100%`**.
- Then you have to remove **`overflow: hidden`** from **`ul.topMenu`** and set a fixed height. Setting **`height: 42px`** will do fine.

**Code:**

```
ul.topMenu ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.topMenu {
    height: 42px;
}
```

**jsFiddle:** → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o9kkb1er/2/).

**Snippet:**

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul.topMenu {
  background: #111;
  height: 42px;
}

ul.topMenu li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.topMenu li a {
  padding: 12px 15px;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: .4s;
  border-right: 1px solid #fff;
}

ul.topMenu li:first-child a {
  border-left: 1px solid #222222;
}

ul.topMenu li a:hover,
ul.topMenu li a:focus {
  background: black;
}

ul.topMenu ul {
  position: relative;
  background: #222;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.topMenu ul li {
  float: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="topMenu" class="topMenu">
  <li><a href="#">Sed ut perspiciatis </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Nemo enim </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sit amet </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Excepteur </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Neque  </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Neque porro </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Ut enim ad </a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Quis autem vel eum </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Sit amet </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Excepteur </a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Neque  </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is better to read more about positions , if we talk about your code you need to give '`position:relative`' to the main `<li>` which is gonna be dropdown, and when its child I mean `<ul>` gets `position:absolute` it is gonna change in order to its relative parent. Giving `width:100%` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `ul` element has always (by default) some padding. So you should add:

```
ul {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Also, if you want the `li`elements to be equal width, you should set some fixed width like:

```
ul li {
 width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to make the ul the same size as the 'li' without having a fix with?

Comment: UL is just wrapper.. so the visible elements are `li` (list items). So you should give fixed with for all the `li`elements if you want them to match.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing 40px of unexpected padding added by webkit. You need to negate this styling by adding your own. for instance one way to mitigate this issue would be to add a style="padding:0;" to the ul in question. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nduT8.png)